# Overlapping HVAC

Tags: thermostat, furnace, heat-pump

I had about a 1,500sq ft single level ranch style home. A few years ago I added on a master suite and a family room, so now about 2100sqft.
The family room has a large pass-through to the rest of the original house and the master suite is more isolated with a short hallway and a door (of course). The addition has a heat pump and the original part of the home has a gas furnace only, no AC.
I live in Seattle, so AC isn't too much of an issue except in the summer and I have a couple of portable AC units I add to the bedrooms when needed.

My question is, is there any way to coordinate the new heat pump with the original furnace in the rest of the house by using smarter thermostats?
I do not expect the heat pump to cool the whole house, I am more concerned with one system trying to heat and the other system trying to cool and wasting a whole bunch of energy since the two systems have a large overlap in the family room space. The furnace has a simple 4-wire style thermostat, and the heat pump has a complicated newer style thermostat (which is consistently 4 degrees off, btw).
The thermostat for the heat pump is in the master bedroom, but the family room has two ducts feeding the far side and a return right over the open passage to the rest of the house and a furnace duct almost directly below this return.

Answer (score 4):

First - the newer thermostat almost certainly has a way to adjust the calibration. On mine it's located in the setup menu. You should be able to fix that 4 degree error in just a few minutes.

Second - the most certain way to avoid the situation you're describing is to switch the systems between heating and cooling mode manually as the seasons change. If you're in the Seattle area it's very rare that you're going to need heat and AC in the same week, and uncommon to need both even in the same month. If you want even fewer touches, just make sure that your setpoints are far enough apart. I also live in the Seattle area, and have never needed cooling and heating in the same day with my setpoints at 68 and 75. Usually there's a month where neither cooling nor heating is needed at all.

If you're trying to hold the temperatures steady to within a degree or two, then you might have this sort of problem. With sensible set points your units will not end up fighting each other ever.

If you really want to integrate the systems, there are commercial control systems that will run multiple HVAC units as an integrated system. A good contractor should be able to set you up with options. They won't be cheap. Personally I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

> I am more concerned with one system trying to heat and the other
> system trying to cool and wasting a whole bunch of energy.

That seems remarkably unlikely with any reasonable thermostat settings on the dumbest of thermostats. In cooling season, the heat-only stat gets set at its lowest setting and stays there until you get to heating season, at which point the other system that includes cooling is unlikely to be in cooling mode, particularly if you use its mode selections to put it in heat mode, rather than "heat or cool as you think best, tiny robot" mode.